# Cannot find symbol class Bind of butterknife

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, butterknife

Somehow I have a mistake in my gradle build. Somehow I cannot find the class Bind of butterknife.

It is probably due to my gradle, but I do not know.

I get this error:

> Error:(40, 6) error: cannot find symbol class Bind

My grade file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.andreasschrade.androidtemplate"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${android_support_lib_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${android_support_lib_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${android_support_lib_version}"

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    //compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'

    // api
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.3.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    compile 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
}
```

Comment: Change minSdkVersion to 15 instead of 14. Or you can use `tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook"`

Answer (score 29):

Use  `@BindView` (butterknife:8.6.0)  instead of `@Bind` (butterknife:7.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

The Latest version 8.8.1 should use @BindView instead of @Bind

Answer (score 0):

You need to change minimum sdk version in your gradle file to 15 instead of 14.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "de.mynameis.androidtemplate"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to update my question, do you have time to have a look at it again

Comment: Can you paste the code where you are using bind class?

Comment: import butterknife.BindView;

Answer (score 0):

First, update your version of Jakexharton:Butterknife on latest

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'
```

And change

```
@Bind
```

to

```
@BindView
```